# Clearing tiles in tile based as3 game

Tags: actionscript-3

I been searching for a way to handle this for hours but have found nothing. In my BuildMap function, I instantiate new MovieClips (Tile) with the instance name cell. Their frame is based on my 2d array (protoMap). The problem is that the cells are instantiated in the function. I don't know how to access them outside of it. I want to removeChild(cell) but the only way I know how is within the function that it's instantiated in.

```
 public function BuildMap()
{
    for (var i:int=0; i < mapHeight; i++)
    {
        for (var u:int=0; u < mapWidth; u++)
        {
            var cell:MovieClip = new Tile();
            cell.gotoAndStop(protoMap[i][u]+1);
            cell.x = tileSide*u;
            cell.y = tileSide*i;
            addChild(cell);

            var currCellLabel:String = cell.currentFrameLabel;
            mapLabels[i].push(currCellLabel);
        }
    }
}
```

I want a function called ClearMap() that loops through again and does removeChild(cell). I thought about doing a clearTiles:Boolean and in BuildMap() do

```
if(clearTiles == false)
{
build the map;
}else{loop again and removeChild(cell)}
```

but that didn't work... so then I tried to pass cell as an argument to BuildMap() but when I tried to remove it, it wasn't an object of the caller... or something like that. I was also thinking to put cell into its own array, but I don't want to waste memory unnecessarily. Any solutions for the noob?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class instead of using functions.

The point of a class is to isolate concerns.
In your case, you want to deal with all those tiles. (create them according to protoMap and be able to delete them all.

Extending a `DisplayObjectContainer` such as `Sprite`, will allow you to add all the tiles to the map object, then you can add and remove the map easily.

Your BuildMap function becomes the constructor.

Here's some non working pseudo code that illustrates the idea:

```
package
{
    public class Map extends Sprite 
    {
        public function Map (data, width, height)
        {
            for (var i:int=0; i < height; i++)
            {
                for (var u:int=0; u < width; u++)
                {
                    var cell:MovieClip = new Tile();
                    cell.gotoAndStop(data[i][u]+1);
                    cell.x = tileSide*u;
                    cell.y = tileSide*i;
                    addChild(cell);

                    var currCellLabel:String = cell.currentFrameLabel;
                    mapLabels[i].push(currCellLabel);
                }
            }
        }

        public function clear():void
        {
            removeChildren();
        }
    }
}
```

The whole map is contained in that class. You'd have to add the labels, but you didn't specify what they are or what they do, so I left them out.

You can use it like so:

```
var awesomeMap:Map = new Map(protoMap, mapWidth, mapHeight);
addChild(awesomeMap);
//later
awesomeMap.clear();
//or
removeChild(awesomeMap);
```

I'd like to point out that building tile maps with `MovieClips` this way is a bad idea. `MovieClips` are horrible for performance, because they carry the overhead of their timeline.
Removing all children is very wasteful, too.

So if you have performance problems, try reusing objects and/or employing a technique called "`blitting`"
See this article: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/blitting_mc.html

Comment: Alright, you're awesome. It's really scary trying to revamp multiple files to fit these changes, though. I know that using MovieClips isn't the best way to go, but I'm pretty new to all of this and it seemed like the easiest way to do it. I read somewhere that with games it's best to just churn out a proof-of-concept as quickly as you can and then optimize later. It's been working for me because trying to think of the best ways before I do anything just keeps me overwhelmed and I never do anything. I figure I'll move my maps to xml, then start trying bitmapData after that. Thank you.

Comment: You certainly do not want to apply premature optimisations, but you don't want to write garbage either. If "never doing anything" is a problem, don't start with a game like this, it's just too big of a project. Start with many smaller things, like creating the map (and just the map). The format you use to serialize your map data into shouldn't matter, think about if adding another one is worth it. ....oh, and if you found that useful, there's this little tick you can click. If it was not useful, please specify what's still unclear =)

Comment: It was perfectly clear. I really appreciate it. I'm still getting used to multiple classes and arguments. So I'll keep this on file for when I'm a bit more comfortable. For now, I'll move onto something else. Thanks again!

Comment: I used this on another project. A map creation program. Now I have another problem. I want to be able to click a tile, load the frame image into a "heldTile" box, display its currentFrameLabel, etc. How can I access and change the cell MoveClips from another function?

Comment: Alright... Create an object from the movieclip containing all of the data I need for the heldTile object and push it to a new array (heldTileData). Got it. So, I have yet another question... I've been playing with bitmapData and I got it to build the map using only the bitmapData of each frame. I only instantiate one movieclip and create multiple objects based off of what frame the mapArray makes it build. It's tough to word. If you understand... will it be better on performance this way?